# jQuery.when function, can't get value after the ajax call has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make the jQuery.when function work.

I have a function test, that connects to another script and retrieves the **firstName** value.

This works, I can see the value if I do a console.log

But I can't seem to make that value available in the **.done function**

Any ideas why?

```
function test (email, key) {

        if (!isEmpty(email) && !isEmpty(key)) {

            var script = getScriptUrl(email, key);

            return  jQuery.ajax({
                        url : script,
                        dataType: 'script',
                        success : function() {
                            // This function retrieves the fisrtname value
                            firstName = getScriptUrlFunction('FirstName');
                        }
                    });
        }
    }



$.when(

    test(email, key)

).done(function(aa1) {

    // This shows undefined - how do I get the firstName here?
    // Why doesn't it work?

    console.log(aa1);

});
```

**Here is the console of aa1:**

```
[undefined, "success", Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success", more...}]
```

Is there a way to get the **firstname** value from **aa1**? Basically pass it to **aa1**?

Ty!

Comment: are you sure `!isEmpty(email) && !isEmpty(key)` is true? Why is your dataType script? are you really requesting another javascript file and expecting it to return a value?

Comment: After I get that script, firstName = getScriptUrlFunction('FirstName');  --- the getScriptUrlfunction returns the firstname value

Comment: `firstName` is global, just access it.

Comment: I could store everything globally, that would work - i just wanted to learn how to do it like the above, retrieve it from the .done function

Comment: right, i was just pointing out that you've already got access to it. the answer below is the correct way to do it with promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.then()` chaining instead of the `success` callback:

```
return $.ajax({ ... })
    .then(function() { return getFirstName(...); });
```